# Add multiple additional documents apart from signing documnet using API

Tags: docusignapi

Is there any way to add  additional documents (which is not a signing document) while sending envelope to DocuSign.We are using DocuSign API to send envelope so is there any API for same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is easy to add additional documents to the envelope. If you don't want them signed, don't add a signhere tab to the additional documents.

See example 2, [available in multiple languages](https://github.com/docusign?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=eg-03&type=&language=) and curl/raw api. It creates an envelope that includes three different documents, a pdf, docx, and html doc.